# replace div with its content

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

i am trying to filter an html code

the code contains a div's with row class

i want to replace these div's with there contents

for ex:

```
<div class="row anotherClass">some html code 1</div>
<div class="row anotherClass">some html code 2</div>
<div class="row anotherClass">some html code 3</div>
```

output should be like this

```
some html code 1
some html code 2
some html code 3
```

i have wrote the following expression (i am not very good with regex) but the output html is still not well filtered some times the div beginning still exist some times the div end still exist

```
$output = preg_replace_callback('/<div class="row (.*?)">(.*)<\/div>/s', function ($matches) {
            return $matches[2];

        }, $output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
<?php

$html = '<div class="row anotherClass">some html code 1</div>
<div class="row anotherClass">some html code 2</div>
<div class="row anotherClass">some html code 3</div>';

$reg = '(<div class="row anotherClass">(.*?)</div>)';
preg_match_all($reg, $html, $divs);

$div_contents = $divs[1];
$divs = $divs[0];

$replaced_html = $html;

for ($i=0; $i < count($divs); $i++) {
    $replaced_html = str_replace($divs[$i], $div_contents[$i], $replaced_html);
}

echo $replaced_html;

?>
```

Comment: thanks for replaying

the the function is working after some modification but the output html is broken the input goes into the errorMessage div

here is an example

Comment: $html = '<div class="row field_Title">
<div class="req"><h4><label class="required">Title <span class="required">*</span></label>: </h4><div class="p"> <div class="errorMessage" style="display:none"></div> <input type="text" maxlength="100" />  </div></div></div>';

$reg = '/<div class="row (.*?)">(.*?)<\/div>./sm';
preg_match_all($reg, $html, $divs);

$div_contents = $divs[2];
$divs = $divs[0];
print_r($div_contents);
$replaced_html = $html;

for ($i=0; $i < count($divs); $i++) {
    $replaced_html = str_replace($divs[$i], $div_contents[$i], $replaced_html);
}

echo $replaced_html;

Comment: there is issue with inner divs

Comment: Try $reg = '/<div class="row (.*?)">(.*?)<\/div>./sm'; replace $reg = '/(<div class="row (.*?)">(.*?)<\/div>.)/sm';